# Grammatically correct expression similar to the {～って感じ} slang

Tags: slang, expressions

Is there a grammatically correct expression similar to the {～って感じ} slang?

For example, I heard something like the following conversation in an anime:

> A: テストはどう?
>   B: どうって? 「もう死にてぇ」って感じだぜ。
>   A: アハハ。何だそれ?

What grammatically correct expression should B-san replace the {～って感じ} part with, while retaining similar nuance, emphasis and emotion?

Comment: Just as a side note: って感 is not grammatically incorrect. It's just slang.

Comment: I've never seen って+noun before, only って+verb. Can a noun follow って?

Comment: って is an informal form of either と or という. In the second case it can sure come before a noun, and it's actually quite common: ってこと, って意味, etc.

Comment: +1, I use this way more than I should.

Comment: I don't think って感じ is incorrect.

Comment: While we're listing the other uses of って, we would be remiss to neglect the use of って at the end of a sentence to mark a quote; in this case, って substitutes for といった: 「明日帰るって。」

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking.  As other people said, って感じだ is grammatically correct.  It is fairly informal, so first I thought that you were looking for a more formal expression, but you write “retaining similar nuance,” which suggests to me that you are _not_ looking for a more formal expression.

Comment: @Tsuyoshi Ito: How is  って感 grammatically correct? I don't have って mentioned in any grammar papers other then to say that it is used to replace (orally) と and others. って is clearly grammatically incorrect (or just nonexistent). Widely used in many contexts, formal or not, but it doesn't exist as a grammar item.

Comment: @repecmps: If your grammar book does not mention って used in place of という, it simply means that your book does not list everything.  http://dic.yahoo.co.jp/dsearch?enc=UTF-8&p=%E3%81%A3%E3%81%A6&dtype=0&dname=0ss&stype=0&index=113135000000&pagenum=1

Comment: @Tsuyoshi: read my comments on Boaz's answer and you will maybe understand that って doesn't exist in grammar. If you don't understand, then I have nothing more to say on the subject, I cannot help you.

Comment: @repecmps: No, I do not understand, and you do not have to help me about this matter.  What you are saying sounds like “～してくださいました is grammatically incorrect because it appeared as an 音便 (おんびん; morphophonological alternation) of ～してくださりました,” but that is absurd.

Comment: @Tsuyoshi: This has **absolutely** no relation with the argument about って, it's not the same kind of alteration, there is history and explanation behind it while って is some simple slang ffs. Now people are mixing Keigo usage with 「もう死にてぇ」って! oh well. Thanks, that really helped with the debate. I will not waste time anymore. You have my points below (and I have... nothing from you, no source, nothing) Enjoy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you can always use `～という感じがする` or `～という感じです`, which, I guess, is where `～って感じ` comes from.

Comment: I'd include　～と感じている so as not to let people think って is always translated as という

Comment: @repecmps: Although って can mean と sometimes, ～と感じている doesn't match the meaning conveyed by って感じ in this question.

Comment: @Derek: How is that? What's the meaning conveyed by って感じ other than "i feel like ~"? Also って doesn't **sometimes** mean と but **most of the time** since this is what it means when って is in front of a verb.

Comment: @repecmps: As I stated, *in this question*, where the subject is the test, you wouldn't say 「もう死にてぇ」と感じている -- it's unnatural Japanese. という感じだ is a far better substitution. The fact that って often equates to と when it's in front of a verb (how often is anyone's guess) does not apply here, because って is in front of a noun. I'm fine with you mentioning that って is not always という, but *in this context* ～と感じている doesn't work and Boaz is right to leave it out.

Comment: 1- If ～と感じている doesn't work in this context, then 「もう死にてぇ」という感じだ doesn't work either. It's not about context. 感じている is grammatically correct and thus can be used. (do you have other arguments than "it doesn't work" or "it's unnatural"?) 2- どうって? 「もう死にてぇ」という感じです is not only completely unnatural but it mixes styles in a single sentence.

Comment: @repecmps: Grammatical correctness does not necessarily equal contextual correctness. My point concerns the latter, not the former. As for which is more "natural", I regret not being a native speaker, since it sounds like that's what it would take to persuade you over to my side of the fence. Oh well. I've made my point and have nothing further to say here.

Comment: anyway -1, this answer is far below what Boaz got us used to. I'm afraid the 2 sentences proposed don't "retain similar nuance, emphasis and emotion" as displayed in the original sentence and the answer is not complete and gives the feeling it was written in 30 seconds.

Comment: @repecmps: You are free to feel what you want. This is indeed not a long and all-encompassing answer, and it's not very detailed. But wasn't much to say here really, and I said what I could in the comments. I didn't include `と感じている`, because it's not equivalent and as Derek has stated - it won't work in all cases. The grammatical difference between `という感じだ` and `と感じている` is that the former is impersonal ("The feeling is ...") and the latter is personal ("I feel that ...").

Comment: @Boaz & Derek: Lukman asked for a grammatically correct form of って感 and  ～と感じている is just that. If there's a grammatical difference with という感じだ that's great. So what? **This discussion is completely absurd. We've come to a point were people actually say ～と感じている is not "a similar form of って感"**. Coming from both of you it's frightening and worrying for the quality of future answers...

Comment: @repecmps: I really don't understand what you're trying to say. って感 is 100% grammatically correct. If it wasn't grammatically correct, native speakers wouldn't be using it, end of story. It's very colloquial and that's why there's an equivalent form which is moral formal and polite was given.

Comment: @Boaz: って is the "abbreviation" (音変化 is the correct word) of と and others. It doesn't exist grammatically. It has not grammatical support. It's not a particle, not an adverb, it's nothing but a spoken habit to replace some words. Saying that it's grammatically correct because natives use it is purely stupid. When I speak French I often use grammatically incorrect sentences because this is how we speak, it doesn't make it correct.

Comment: Anticipating your next argument; http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp and http://dic.search.yahoo.co.jp: "「と」...の音変化とも"; http://www.excite.co.jp: "cannot find って"; http://www.weblio.jp: "「とて」の転"; http://www.sanseido.net: "cannot find って".  If saying って is grammatically correct makes you happy and giving poor arguments makes you feel important, that's fine, enjoy yourself. I have wasted enough time on this and will not answer you again on this issue.

Comment: @repecmps: I have no idea what you mean by "exist grammatically". って is a particle, which is historically a contraction (probably of とて). Putting aside Internet dictionaries, You can find it Daijirin and Kōjien if you really want, but it has to be a very sad day when you decide what is grammar and what is not according to dictionaries. Lexicographers have nothing to do with grammar.

Comment: And you should know the difference between "grammatically incorrect" and "non-standard" or "low register" language. If I say "It's me" in English, there are many grammar douchebags who would just be horrified that I didn't say "It is I", but these says nothing about whether that grammar is correct or not. "Correct grammar" is not what the self-appointed grammar snubs of whatever language call "correct". Correct grammar, if anything, is this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grammaticality. You're talking about this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prescriptive_linguistics.